# Plot axvline from Point to Point in Matplotlib Python 3.6

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, python-3.6

I am reading Data from a Simulation out of an Excel File. Out of this Data I generated two DataFrames containing 200 values. Now i want to plot all the Values from DataFrame one in blue and all Values from DataFrame two in purple. Therefore I have following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("###CENSORED####.xlsx", sheetname="Data")

unpatched = df["Unpatched"][:-800]
patched = df["Patched"][:-800]
x = range(0,len(unpatched))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.scatter(x, unpatched, zorder=10, )
plt.scatter(x, patched, c="purple",zorder=19,)
```

This results in following Graph:

[image]

But now i want to draw in some lines that visualize the difference between the blue and purple dots. I thought about an orange line going from blue dot at simulation-run x to the purple dot at simulation-run x. I've tried to "cheat" with following code, since I'm pretty new to matplotlib.

```
scale_factor = 300
for a in x:
   plt.axvline(a, patched[a]/scale_factor, unpatched[a]/scale_factor, c="orange")
```

But this resulted in a inaccuracy as seen seen below:

[image]

So is there a smarter way to do this? I've realized that the axvline documentation only says that ymin, ymax can only be scalars. Can I somehow turn my given values into fitting scalars?

Comment: It looks like you're rather looking for `plt.vlines(x, patched.values, unpatched.values)`

Comment: oh wow...  so what is the exact difference between axvline and vline? I mean this simple change just solved my problem, but I'm still interested in it.

Comment: In `axvline` the y coordinates are axes coordinates (between 0 and 1). But here you want to use normal data coordinates.